# Как программно заменить один цвет на картинке в Андроид?

Tags: android

Использую в приложении PNG-картинку с прозрачным фоном и двумя цветами, один из которых черный. Вроде такой:

[image: пример]

Возможно ли программно заменить голубой цвет на красный? Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Можно по разному. Я бы для начала попробовал порезать картинку (чтобы каждая линия была отдельной картинкой) после чего поместил бы их внутрь слоёв LayerDrawable, которые бы программно получал и применял бы к ним ColorFilter. Это может сработать.

Comment: Вариант. Но было бы интересно найти целиком программное решение.

Comment: Если переделать в VectorDrawable, то вот тут показано как отдельные части можно модифицировать: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58172220/3212712

Comment: Да, с VectorDrawable работает. С PNG решения не нашел, использую VectorDrawable. Спасибо!

Comment: Если, хотя бы и кратко, опишите как в итоге сделали в ответе - наверняка многим полезно будет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совету @ЮрийСПб заменил картинки на VectorDrawable, сконвертировав их средствами студии из SVG. А далее с помощью библиотеки [VectorMaster](https://github.com/harjot-oberai/VectorMaster) заменяю у нужных слоев цвета:

```
val vectorMasterDrawable = VectorMasterDrawable(context, R.drawable.my_image)
val layer = vectorMasterDrawable.getPathModelByName("layer1")
layer.setStrokeColor(Color.RED)
layer.setFillColor(Color.RED)
```